# jQuery-File-Upload - TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I have my html/js code in my simple page JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<body>

<form id="MyID" method="post" action="JSFPAGE" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>Select files...</span>
      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span><br><br>
<!-- The global progress bar -->
<div id="progress" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
<div id="files" class="files">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'xUpload.xsp';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
</form>
</body>
```

this is very simple...and all the JS resource are OK.
But in the console I see this error:

***TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function
$('#fileupload').fileupload({***

Have you any suggest for my problem?

Comment: do you have any solution ? I have same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this for myself by going to the demo site BlueImp has online. The GitHub repo for this project can be found at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. If you look at their source code, it becomes apparent that you need two files to help this work on your project. 1. [jquery.ui.widget.js](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js) and 2. [jquery.fileupload.js](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js).

If you include these files in your app, the code for the fileupload will work. You'll need the UI widget document as a dependency for the fileupload file.

In case you are looking for a working example of this, Heroku has a decent write up that will help guide you regardless of if you are using Heroku or not. [Direct to S3 Image Uploads in Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails)

Happy coding!

Comment: For anyone who has still issues with this - check if you download correctly the .js files. I did download the html page with the file by mistake. Then it is good idea to clear the browser cache and reload your page.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, I just moved the js files before closing the `body` tag and it worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<body>

<form id="MyID" method="post" action="JSFPAGE" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>Select files...</span>
      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span><br><br>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'xUpload.xsp';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
       ...
});
</script>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I made same thing but still not stable :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had to go through this issue again, so you don't have to use up to around 3 days like i did on this problem:

-You should make sure you don't have multiple jquery plugins on your project, even if it doesn't load and you shouldn't use a block tag to load the js files on your page.

-You should move all the files to your base html if you are extending the page and you should follow the order of the documents

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/customUploader.js' %}"></script>
```